# Turn all check boxes to false in total workbook

Tags: google-apps-script

I've used the following script to uncheck checkboxes on an active spreadsheet.

```
function ResetCheckboxesOnSheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getDataValidations();
  var cbA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      var rule=vA[i][j];
      if(rule!=null) {
        var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
        if(criteria == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
          sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).setValue(false)

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm trying to figure out if I can uncheck the boxes on a workbook. I have 38 timesheets, 38 different tabs. Each employee has 5 or 6 different questions to check a true or false checkbox.  I would like to be able to uncheck all the check boxes on all 38 tabs by running the script one time.

Comment: Check documentation for `range.uncheck()`

Comment: About `I have 38 timesheets, 38 different tabs.`, you have 38 Google Spreadsheets including 38 sheets in each Spreadsheet. You want to uncheck all checkboxes in `38 x 38 = 1,444` sheets using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It's the same Range in all tabs where the checkboxes are? Like for example A1:A5. You have so many tabs that you should consider the [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this so I'm probably not using the correct verbage.  I have 1 workbook with 38 tabs, each tab is for 1 employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to uncheck all checkboxes in every sheet inside a Spreadsheet, you can do it by using the [uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck) method. This is an example code on how you would do it:

```
function uncheckAllBoxes() {
  // Get the Spradsheet linked to this Apps Script project
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Get all sheets in the Spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // Uncheck all checkboxes in every sheet
  sheets.forEach((sheet) => sheet.getDataRange().uncheck());
}
```

### Notice:

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) will return a 2D array with all the sheet values.
- Keep in mind the [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) because you are handling a Spreadsheet with a big amount of sheets.

Comment: Tried this and it came back in the Log TypeError:Cannot read property 'getSheets' of null at uncheckAllBoxes(Code:5:19)

Comment: Is your Apps Script project linked to your spreadsheet? You could also try ``` var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your-spreadsheet-id ");``` instead of ```var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();```. You can find your spreadsheet's id on the url when you open. Example ```https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/your-spreadsheet-id/edit```

Comment: It looks like that's the one that's going to work.  Guess I'm not supposed to use the word Th---- so I appreciate the help

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider mark it as the correct answer in order to let other people in the future know my answer works. You can check [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through the entire workbook. This should do it for you:

```
function KillALlChecks(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allSheets = ss.getSheets();

allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    ResetCheckboxesOnSheet(sheet);
    }
}



function ResetCheckboxesOnSheet(sh) {

  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getDataValidations();
  var cbA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      var rule=vA[i][j];
      if(rule!=null) {
        var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
        if(criteria == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
          sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).setValue(false)

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This came back with the TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of null (line 3, file "Code")